What is wrong in this clerk middleware setup?
I want to know that what is wrong in this clerk middleware setup? Is there annything wrong or its correct?
middleware.ts:
import { clerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export default clerkMiddleware({
publicRoutes: \[
'/',
'/events/:id',
'/api/webhook/clerk',
'/api/webhook/stripe',
'/api/uploadthing'
\],
ignoredRoutes :\[
'/api/webhook/clerk',
'/api/webhook/stripe',
'/api/uploadthing'
\]
});

export const config = {
matcher: \[
// Skip Next.js internals and all static files, unless found in search params
'/((?!\_next|\[^?\]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
// Always run for API routes
'/(api|trpc)(.\*)',
\],
};

I am getting a squiggly line on publicRoutes, and am unable to understand why it's there.

When you hover the cursor over the squiggly lines, do you get any more details in a tooltip? Of course, the question whether it's wrong can only really be answered by you when you try it out/debug. Do you get the results you expect.

Do you mean a squiggly line in your IDE? If so it should tell you.

I guess you can just follow the official docs and create your protected routes like this :


import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from '@clerk/nextjs/server'

const isProtectedRoute = createRouteMatcher(['/dashboard(.*)', '/forum(.*)'])

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req) => {
  if (isProtectedRoute(req)) auth().protect()
})

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip Next.js internals and all static files, unless found in search params
    '/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
    // Always run for API routes
    '/(api|trpc)(.*)',
  ],
}



And by that it already ignores the rest of the routes so you dont need to define the ignored routes.
The doc:https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/clerk-middleware
